# Symfony2 - How to iterate through an associative array in Twig and eliminate duplicates?

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

I am working on a Report which is mapped with Docrtrine I have an entity DL01, and I want to access specific array key & values to display the output in the following format

My Associative array {{ Dump() }} of DL01_data is below

```
array(2) { 
 [0]=> array(4) { 
         ["zoneName"]=> string(10) "DENMARK"
         ["rank"]=> int(85)
         ["actSanctList"]=> NULL 
         ["offDate"]=> object(DateTime)#5717 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2010-10-25 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" } }
```

My controller returns this

`return $this->render('TestBundle:Test:DL01.html.twig', array('form' =>   $form->createView(), 'DL01_data' => $DL01));`

I want to display the result of the report in twig in the following format, such that the records are grouped together and displayed one after the another in a nested for loop.
(See pictures)

Current output 
[image]

How can i group records together nested in this format, eliminating the duplicates?

[image]

Twig
I am displaying the report in Twig, in this manner

```
    {% for DL01_line in DL01_data %}
        <tr>
             <td> {{ DL01_data[0].zoneName }} </td>
             <td> {{ DL01_data[0].Rank }} </td>
            <td>{{ DL01_line.actSanctList }}</td>
            <td>{{ DL01_line.offDate|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Samy-Dindane - I have updated my question and looking for an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the array index with `DL01_data[0]`

```
{{ DL01_data[0].zoneName }}
```

or this:

```
{{ DL01_data[0]['zoneName'] }}
```

for iteration of whole array with all keys and values:

```
{% for data in DL01_data %}
    {{ data.zoneName }}
{% endfor %}
```

it work like `foreach` cycle in PHP. 
Or if you need only from 0 to 99 index iteration:

```
{% for data in DL01_data|slice(0,99) %}
    {{ data.zoneName }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: For this use `for`. I updated my answer, check please

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, because I am looking for a syntax for a nested for loop. Like display zoneName and Rank (0,max) where max is the maximum number of elements and display actSanctList and offDate corresponding to the element index value of zoneName and Rank. I need to group them. In other words, I want to display them one by one. I am updating my question.

Comment: Hello @Victor, I added more information about the question along with screenshot of my desired output.